# Test the LaTeX markdown in this sandbox question!

Tags: discussion, mathjax

### Purpose of question

We  have \$\LaTeX\$ support through [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)!  Now, instead of writing equations like this:

```
w0 = 1 / sqrt(L * C)
```

we can write:

\$\displaystyle \omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$

Beautiful! However, TeX has a steep learning curve, and it will take some time to figure out how to use this feature.  This question is a sandbox in which to practice its use.

### Documentation

You'll see in the right sidebar, when writing a question, the line:

> MathJaX[sic] equations `\$sin^2\theta\$`

and a [link to generic TeX help](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/).  I find that the [math mode](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/node17.html#SECTION00080000000000000000) section is most helpful.  The [special symbols](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/node21.html) article is particularly useful:

\$\$ \alpha \beta \mu \Omega \omega \theta \$\$

Note that not all of TeX is included; you'll get this message if you try to include a module that's not in MathJax, such as Tabular:

\$\begin{tabular}1 & 2\\3 & 4\end{tabular}\$

### How did they do that?

You can always get at the source by right-clicking an equation.  A MathJax context menu will come up, like the following:

[image: Context Menu with Show Math As - TeX Commands highlighted]

(*some versions of MathJax use Show Source menu*) [image: Context Menu with Show Source highlighted]

and "Show Math As - TeX Commands" will bring up a window with the source for the equations.  Just drop the text contained `\$`between a pair of escaped dollar signs!`\$`  Or, you can `$$`surround it with two dollar signs for centering.`$$`

### Begin \$\LaTeX\$ Sandbox

The markdown for a question should be identical to what you get from an answer, but I'll leave the rest of this question for testing more TeX in case that assumption is mistaken.

Note: This is a recreated version of the [original MathJax sandbox question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question). At some point, that post evolved to [cause crashing in some web browsers](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7432/the-latex-sandbox-question-is-crashing-the-page), and was deleted.

Comment: Test: \$P \centernot\implies Q\$. Test: \$ P \;\not\!\!\!\implies Q \$.

Answer (score 10):

Some MathJax frequently used here:

Equation in-line: `\$123\$` \$\rightarrow\$ \$123\$

Equation centered on a separate line: `$$123$$` \$\rightarrow\$ $$123$$

Fractions:  1/2 \$\rightarrow\$ `\$\frac{1}{2}\$` \$\rightarrow\$ \$\frac{1}{2}\$

Bigger fractions:  1/2 \$\rightarrow\$ `\$\dfrac{1}{2}\$` \$\rightarrow\$ \$\dfrac{1}{2}\$

Something enclosed by full parentheses: (1/2) \$\rightarrow\$ `\$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\$` \$\rightarrow\$ \$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\$

Exponent: I^2 \$\rightarrow\$ `\$I^2\$` \$\rightarrow\$ \$I^2\$

Exponent: e^-1 \$\rightarrow\$ `\$e^{-1}\$` \$\rightarrow\$ \$e^{-1}\$ ... or `\$e^{\text{-1}}\$` \$\rightarrow\$ \$e^{\text{-1}}\$

Subscript: t0 \$\rightarrow\$ `\$t_0\$` \$\rightarrow\$ \$t_0\$

Removing the italics from previous: \$\rightarrow\$ `\text{t}_0` \$\rightarrow\$ \$\text{t}_0\$ (now omitting `\$` tags for display brevity but they are still required.)

Square Root: sqrt(9) \$\rightarrow\$ `\sqrt{9}` \$\rightarrow\$ \$\sqrt{9}\$

Cubic Root: ? \$\rightarrow\$ `\sqrt[3]{27}` \$\rightarrow\$ \$\sqrt[3]{27}\$

Greek symbols: `\alpha` \$\alpha\quad\$
`\beta` \$\beta\quad\$
`\gamma` \$\gamma\quad\$
`\delta` \$\delta\quad\$
`\epsilon` \$\epsilon\quad\$
`\varepsilon` \$\varepsilon\quad\$
`\zeta` \$\zeta\quad\$
`\eta` \$\eta\quad\$
`\theta` \$\theta\quad\$
`\vartheta` \$\vartheta\quad\$
`\iota` \$\iota\quad\$
`\kappa` \$\kappa\quad\$
`\lambda` \$\lambda\quad\$
`\mu` \$\mu\quad\$
`\nu` \$\nu\quad\$
`\xi` \$\xi\quad\$
`\omicron` \$\omicron\quad\$
`\pi` \$\pi\quad\$
`\varpi` \$\varpi\quad\$
`\rho` \$\rho\quad\$
`\varrho` \$\varrho\quad\$
`\sigma` \$\sigma\quad\$
`\varsigma` \$\varsigma\quad\$
`\tau` \$\tau\quad\$
`\upsilon` \$\upsilon\quad\$
`\phi` \$\phi\quad\$
`\varphi` \$\varphi\quad\$
`\chi` \$\chi\quad\$
`\psi` \$\psi\quad\$
`\omega` \$\omega\quad\$
`\Gamma` \$\Gamma\quad\$
`\Delta` \$\Delta\quad\$
`\Theta` \$\Theta\quad\$
`\Lambda` \$\Lambda\quad\$
`\Sigma` \$\Sigma\quad\$
`\Upsilon` \$\Upsilon\quad\$
`\Psi` \$\Psi\quad\$
`\Omega` \$\Omega\quad\$

Comparisons: i < 5 \$\rightarrow\$ `i\lt 5` \$\rightarrow\$ \$i\lt 5\$ ...
`\neq` \$\rightarrow \:\neq\quad\$
`\approx` \$\rightarrow \:\approx\quad\$
`\simeq` \$\rightarrow \:\simeq\quad\$

Operators: `\times` \$\rightarrow \:\times\quad\$
`\pm` \$\rightarrow \:\pm\quad\$
`\cdot` \$\rightarrow \:\cdot\quad\$
`\oplus` \$\rightarrow \:\oplus\quad\$
`\infty` \$\rightarrow \:\infty\quad\$

Trigonometry: sin(x) \$\rightarrow\$ `\sin x` \$\rightarrow\$ \$\sin x\$

Logs: nat log(n) \$\rightarrow\$ `\ln x` \$\rightarrow\$ \$\ln x\$ ...
`\log_{20}(x)` \$\rightarrow \:\log_{20}(x)\quad\$

Sum: `\sum_{a=1} ^{B} c` \$\rightarrow  \sum_{a=1} ^{B} c\$

Product: `\prod_{a=1} ^{B} c`  \$\rightarrow  \prod_{a=1} ^{B} c\$

Integral: `\int_{0} ^{\infty} x dx` \$\rightarrow \int_{0} ^{\infty} x dx\$

Limit: `\lim_{x \to \infty}` \$\rightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty}\$

Overline: /nRESET \$\rightarrow\$ `\overline{\text{nRESET}}` \$\rightarrow\$ \$\overline{\text{nRESET}}\$

Vector: `\vec{x}` \$\rightarrow\$ \$\vec{x}\$ also `\overrightarrow{x}` \$\rightarrow\$ \$\overrightarrow{x}\$

Answer (score 6):

Sadly there is no siunitx support, so to get the units right, it gets a bit clumsy like this:

3 V \$\rightarrow\$ `3~\text{V}` \$\rightarrow\$ \$3~\text{V}\$

The `~` is there to generate the space and as units are written upright and not in italics we need to use `\text{unit}`

As Massimo Ortolando suggests using `\,` typesets a smaller space, which is used in the siunitx package to make the combination look more like a single entity:

3 V \$\rightarrow\$ `3\,\text{V}` \$\rightarrow\$ \$3\,\text{V}\$

Instead of just having \SI{3}{\volt}.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately `siunitx` is not supported is any site. For the space, I suggest to use the small space `\,`, which better represents the fact that the quantity is a single object (`siunitx` uses this).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano nice, thanks for that. I incorporated this in my answer and the difference is small but visible.

Answer (score 4):

#### MathJax resources on the other stackexchange sites:

meta.SE: Which Sites Use MathJax -- [Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)

meta.SE: questions tagged MathJax -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax?tab=Active

**math.SE: MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference --** https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

6. **Parentheses**

Ordinary symbols `()` `[]` make parentheses and brackets \$(2+3)[4+4]\$.
Use `\{` and `\}` for curly braces \$\{\}\$.

These do *not* scale with the formula in between,
so if you write `(\frac{\sqrt x}{y^3})` the parentheses will be too small:
\$(\frac{\sqrt x}{y^3})\$.
Using `\left(` … `\right)` will make the sizes adjust automatically to the formula they enclose:
`\left(\frac{\sqrt x}{y^3}\right)` is
\$\left(\frac{\sqrt x}{y^3}\right)\$.

`\left` and `\right` apply to all the following sorts of parentheses:
`(` and `)` \$(x)\$,
`[` and `]` \$[x]\$,
`\{` and `\}` \$\{x\}\$,
`|` \$|x|\$,
`\vert` \$\vert x \vert\$,
`\Vert` \$\Vert x \Vert\$,
`\langle` and `\rangle` \$\langle x \rangle\$,
`\lceil` and `\rceil` \$\lceil x \rceil\$,
`\lfloor` and `\rfloor` \$\lfloor x \rfloor\$.
`\middle` can be used to add additional dividers.

`\left[\frac{\sqrt x}{y^3}\right]` is
\$\left[\frac{\sqrt x}{y^3}\right]\$.

There are also invisible parentheses, denoted by `.`:
`\left.\frac12\right\rbrace` is \$\left.\frac12\right\rbrace\$.

If manual size adjustments are required:  `\Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((x)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)` gives \$\Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((x)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)\$.

**Fractions**

`\frac{a+1}{b+1}` is \$\frac{a+1}{b+1}\$
`{a+1\over b+1}` is \${a+1\over b+1}\$

**Roots**

Use `sqrt`, which adjusts to the size of its argument:
`\sqrt{x^3}` \$\sqrt{x^3}\$
`\sqrt[3]{\frac xy}` \$\sqrt[3]{\frac xy}\$
`\left({\frac qr}\right)^{1/2}` \$\left({\frac qr}\right)^{1/2}\$

`\operatorname{myfunction}(x)` \$\operatorname{myfunction}(x)\$

Answer (score 3):

Matrices:

```
$$G_{\text{MNA}} = \begin{bmatrix}
g_1 & -g_1 & \cdots \\
-g_1 & g_1 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
\end{bmatrix}$$
```

$$G_{\text{MNA}} = \begin{bmatrix}
g_1 & -g_1 & \cdots \\
-g_1 & g_1 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Cases:

```
$$I_\text{LED} = \begin{cases} (V - V_F) / R;& V > V_F\\ 0;&V < V_F\end{cases} $$
```

$$I_\text{LED} = \begin{cases} (V - V_F) / R;& V > V_F\\ 0;&V < V_F\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a resource I found useful

https://arachnoid.com/latex/

(be sure to click the "mathjax" radio button, as it has other latex renderings too)

Answer (score 1):

Test $$ P \centernot \implies Q $$.

Answer (score 1):

Made this [little JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juanmf/Lz7nycxm/latest/) for basic Markup + Latex editing.

Hope it helps, serves as a nice tool to play around before asking a question, or prepare a paper...

** EDIT: check this out https://hackmd.io/
Has support for latex and uml on top of markdown.